# The system database file master.mdf already exists in C:\

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2016-express

I am trying ti add some new features to my already installed Sql Server instance.

I run the installation setup and chose the option to add new features to existing instance of Sql Server 2016 RC3. Checked the options I wanted to add and then continued to next step. At the step where I add Authentication Mode and the server administrators I am having an error like below in the image.

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

The problems is obvious but is it obligatory to 'delete' `master.mdf` file and `tempdb.mdf` file before starting the installation or do something else ?

I dont want to change the locations of the master db files because I dont want to create two directories for the same purpose with two databases with the same purpose again.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the master data file *is*. Your example pictures clearly show you are adding system databases so this is not adding features as much as it is installing an Instance.

Comment: Sql Server 2016 **RC3**? There is no reason to be running a beta version of sql server at this point. And it is also not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Open Explorer and navigate to the folder in question (in my case):
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA`

- Control-A (select all), Control-X (cut)
- Create a new folder: `DATA_OLD`
- Go into the DATA_OLD folder, Control-V (paste)

You can now install SQL Server. Note: You will have to re-link any previously existing databases from the DATA_OLD folder.